# Insert daily totals in data table

Tags: google-sheets

My data table looks like this:

| Date | Fruits | Inventory | Rotted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan 1 | Apple | 100 | 1 |
| Jan 1 | Kiwi | 100 | 2 |
| Jan 1 | Pear | 100 | 1 |
| Jan 2 | Apple | 90 | 5 |
| Jan 2 | Kiwi | 80 | 3 |
| Jan 2 | Pear | 70 | 1 |
| Jan 3 | Apple | 80 | 5 |
| Jan 3 | Kiwi | 70 | 3 |
| Jan 3 | Pear | 50 | 1 |

The goal: Track total pieces of fruit I have over time.

Problem: I'm getting the data fed directly from a CSV on a server to my Google Sheet and I want to count the total pieces of fruit for each day on the Google Sheet by adding a new row each day that says "all fruit".

How can I insert daily totals in the data table like shown below?

| Date | Fruits | Inventory | Rotted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan 1 | Apple | 100 | 1 |
| Jan 1 | Kiwi | 100 | 2 |
| Jan 1 | Pear | 100 | 1 |
| Jan 1 | TOTAL | 300 | 4 |
| Jan 2 | Apple | 90 | 5 |
| Jan 2 | Kiwi | 80 | 3 |
| Jan 2 | Pear | 70 | 1 |
| Jan 2 | TOTAL | 240 | 8 |
| Jan 3 | Apple | 80 | 5 |
| Jan 3 | Kiwi | 70 | 3 |
| Jan 3 | Pear | 50 | 1 |
| Jan 3 | TOTAL | 200 | 8 |

I am currently fetching the data table to a Google Sheet with this formula:

`=IMPORTDATA("https://xxx.xxx/fruits.csv")`

Is there a way I can automatically add a "all fruits total" row to the dataset on Google Sheet daily?

Comment: You should better use the pivot table to get the total per day.

Comment: Hi @MikeSteelson. You are right. But for the purpose of this table, I wanted to insert a new row. I've updated the question on what I want the table to eventually look like.

Comment: Please mention why would you want to have a total row in the original data. This is typically not a best-practice. There could be other ways to achieve your goal than adding total row.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a mini report through **Insert > New sheet** and this formula in cell A1 of the new sheet:

```
=query( 
  importdata("https://xxx.xxx/fruits.csv"), 
  "select Col1, sum(Col3), sum(Col4) 
   where Col1 is not null 
   group by Col1", 
  1 
)
```

To get full report that includes all data and the totals, try this:

```
=query( 
  { 
    importdata("https://xxx.xxx/fruits.csv"); 
    query( 
      importdata("https://xxx.xxx/fruits.csv"), 
      "select Col1, 'TOTAL', sum(Col3), sum(Col4) 
       where Col1 is not null 
       group by Col1 
       label Col1 '', 'TOTAL' '', sum(Col3) '', sum(Col4) '' ", 
      1 
    ) 
  }, 
  "order by Col1", 
  1 
)
```

Comment: Thanks man. That was brilliant. Is there a way to insert the row with the original data? I've updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: Edited the answer to include another solution.